# Не работает not в jQuery

Tags: jquery

$('img:not(#div_for_img)').hide(2000); // пытаюсь уменьшить все картинки кроме тех, что с айди #div_for_img, в итоге not вообще не видит, уменьшает всё подряд

Картинки которые не хочу трогать:

Comment: $('img[id!="div_for_img"]').hide(2000); - не работает 
$('img').not('#div_for_img').hide(2000);  - не работает

Comment: У меня работает и мой вариант и вариант @Mihanik71. Возможно id "div_for_img" прописан не для тегов img, а для div-ов в которых эти картинки находяться...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('img[id!="div_for_img"]').hide(2000);
```

Comment: не работает (((

Comment: У меня работает и мой вариант и вариант @Mihanik71. Возможно id "div_for_img" прописан не для тегов img, а для div-ов в которых эти картинки находяться...

Comment: А всё, разобрался, спасибо огромное

Comment: так в чем проблема была?

Comment: id не для тегов как вы и сказали

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img').not('#div_for_img').hide(2000);
```

Comment: не работает (((